# TeamCity: How to checkout second VCS without monitoring changes

Tags: git, teamcity, cicd

Is there a way to add a secondary VCS to a TeamCity On-Premise build configuration, so the git repo is cloned but changes in it are not tracked as part of the build?

I have a unit test build config for a git repo that is a component of my application. I want the build to run when I push changes to the component repo (or set up an MR), so I have a VCS root/trigger set up for this git repository.

In order to build, I *also* need a top-level application repository cloned, but I don't want to monitor changes in it. My desired behavior is this:

1. Change pushed to component repo on a dev branch
2. TC clones HEAD of main branch of top-level application repo
3. TC clones VCS-triggered changeset of component repo (cloned into subdirectory of top-level repo)
4. Run Build/Tests
5. Report results (only list changes in component repo)

I have tried to do this by setting up two VCS roots: One for top-level component, and one for the sub-component. Everything works as expected, *except* that the list of changes in each build also includes all changes in the top-level repo. This also means developers who committed to the main branch of the top-level repo get notified when my unit test build fails for the changes in my component repo dev branch.

Is there any way to set up the top-level VCS so it is able to clone, but not track/report on those changes?

I am not able to change the repository organization, and we are not using git submodules.

Comment: You could add a step with `git clone` command.